# How do I merge many columns with similar column names from the same dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tabular

Firstly, sorry if the format is off, this is my first question here and I'm relatively new to R.

I have a large dataset which looks more or less like this:

| ID | gender | QUESTION1_1 | QUESTION1_2 | QUESTION1_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | F | NA | NA | NA |
| 100002 | M | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 100003 | M | NA | NA | NA |
| 100004 | F | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 100005 | M | NA | NA | NA |

The reason why the question is spread out is because participants were asked to select "all that apply".

For now, I'm looking to merge all Question 1's together by column name to show a value if the question was answered, and another if it wasn't (or just remain NA) - just to see how many answered questions I have per question (rather than per option inside a question).

Ideally, I'd like a code that lets me merge columns by partial string match in the column name, as the dataset is quite large, but I can do it manually.

The closest I got was doing it manually and using the tidiverse package:

```
dat_joined <- as.data.frame(dat) %>%
  unite("QUESTION1", 3:5, remove = TRUE)
```

but it joins the columns in a weird format:

| ID | gender | QUESTION1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | F | NA_NA_NA |
| 100002 | M | 1_0_1 |
| 100003 | M | NA_NA_NA |
| 100004 | F | 0_0_1 |
| 100005 | M | NA_NA_NA |

Is there any solution to this? I'm really struggling with this as most questions I've found here focus on merging columns where the answer matches by partial string, rather than the column name.

Also, I'll eventually have to look into each of the options, which I'm struggling to know where to start. Are there any resources I could look into for this?

---

This is some code to replicate the toy table

```
ID<- c("100001", "100002", "100003", "100004", "100005")
gender <- c("F","M","M","F","M")
QUESTION1_1<- c(NA, "1",NA,"0",NA)
QUESTION1_2<- c(NA, "0",NA,"0",NA)
QUESTION1_3<- c(NA, "1",NA,"0",NA)

dat<- cbind(ID,gender,QUESTION1_1,QUESTION1_2,QUESTION1_3)
dat
```

Comment: "It joins the questions in a weird format" - why do you consider this format to be weird? How would you like the result to be formatted?

Comment: As I explained above, I'd like to have True or 1 if there's an answer, and 0, False or NA if there's no answer, so that I can then count how many have answers and how many don't

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question rightly, this should work:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

dat <- as_tibble(dat) # turn dat into a tibble

# Pivot longer 
long_dat <- 
  pivot_longer(
    dat,
    cols = starts_with("QUESTION"),
    names_to = "question_name",
    values_to = "response") |> 
  mutate(response = as.numeric(response))
# (response is coded as a character variable in your example)

head(long_dat)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   ID     gender question_name response
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1 100001 F      QUESTION1_1         NA
#> 2 100001 F      QUESTION1_2         NA
#> 3 100001 F      QUESTION1_3         NA
#> 4 100002 M      QUESTION1_1          1
#> 5 100002 M      QUESTION1_2          0
#> 6 100002 M      QUESTION1_3          1

## Group dat by ID and question number,
## which we work out from the text of the question name
group_by(long_dat,
         ID, question_number = str_extract(question_name, "\\d+(?=_)")) |> 
  ## Summarise - is the sum of sub-questions greater than 0?
  summarise(any_responses = sum(response) > 0)

#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#> # Groups:   ID [5]
#>   ID     question_number any_responses
#>   <chr>  <chr>           <lgl>   
#> 1 100001 1               NA      
#> 2 100002 1               TRUE    
#> 3 100003 1               NA      
#> 4 100004 1               FALSE   
#> 5 100005 1               NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: same, as above, thanks for the solution, it works perfectly for doing it manually.would there be a way to use this if I have many questions (i.e. columns) with different names (e.g. HOWOFTEN_1, HOWOFTEN_2, WHY_1, WHY_2)?

Comment: I don't think I'm going to be able to help with that. Next time, please construct an example that more accurately reflects the question you would like answered.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pivot_longer`, it's quite straightforward:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("QUESTION"), names_pattern = "QUESTION(\\d+)_(\\d+)", names_to = c("question", "option"), values_drop_na = T) %>%
  mutate(across(-gender, as.numeric),
        gender = as.factor(gender))

# Output
# A tibble: 6 × 5
      ID gender question option value
   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 100002 M             1      1     1
2 100002 M             1      2     0
3 100002 M             1      3     1
4 100004 F             1      1     0
5 100004 F             1      2     0
6 100004 F             1      3     1
```

From here you can ask things like, how many data points I have (options ticked)? (6, the number of rows above), or getting the number of answered questions by:

```
df %>% 
  select(ID, question) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  nrow()
# [1] 2
```

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly for doing it manually. Just to check, is there a way to do it if I have many questions (i.e. columns) with different names (e.g. HOWOFTEN_1, HOWOFTEN_2, WHY_1, WHY_2)?

Comment: @Lynne you could replace/add to the columns which are selected in the pivot_longer function. Update your question with the results of `colnames(df)`